# How can I set the textbox.text in one user control equal to the textbox.text in another?

Tags: vb.net, wpf-4.0

I have a .NET WPF browser app page with 2 user controls. I want textbox.text in user control 2 to equal textbox.text in user control 1.

I have tried `userctrl2.textbox1.text = userctrl1.textbox.text`, but it doesn’t work.

I’m used to Windows Forms-based applications, however WPF works a bit differently. How can I set the textbox.text in user control 2 equal to the textbox.text in user control 1?

Comment: can you elaborate on `doesn’t work`? it is hard to see the screen from where we are sitting

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it the WPF way?

First text box control should bind to a property using two way binding.

Second text box control should bind to a property using one way binding.

When you type in a first text box, it will update the underlying property, and this will in turn notify the second text box control that the property changed.